# I have an error type 3 on android studio and I think it't because of something I deleted on my phone how can I fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, runtime

I think I accidentally deleted something from my phone and now it doesn't run any of my apps and the same error occurs every time! Please help me I have an exam in two days!:(

**Here is the error..**

```
10/15 16:32:14: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi MI 5.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.app2t/com.example.app2t.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.app2t/com.example.app2t.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.app2t/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.app2t/com.example.app2t.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the manifest or build.gradle? Did you try cleaning the project? Did you try restarting Android Studio or even rebooting your PC?

Comment: But I think the problem it's not in the project because my app was running just fine and then I got a notification on my phone about running out of space and I deleted some thinks among them, some apps I had run before. After that I tried to run my app on the phone again and this error occurred. I tried to run other projects as well and the same error showed up. I didn't change anything on the code

Comment: You could try running your app in an emulator. You could back up all the data on your phone and do a factory reset. You could borrow a friend's phone. Did you search stackoverflow for others having the same problem?

Comment: It looks like your app is no longer on your phone. Try rebuilding and reinstalling your app. Can you launch your app from the HOME screen?

Comment: My pc is not so strong to run apps with the emulator. 
Fortunately when I did a new project it was running just fine on my phone! 
It just not able to run the other apps that I already have, but I rebuilt and reinstalled them all again. Thank you so much for your responses and your advises!